# Non-required arguments in compojure-api/schema/swagger?

Tags: clojure, swagger, plumatic-schema, compojure-api

When I have a definition of an API like this:

```
(POST* "/register" []
    :body-params [username :- String,
                  password :- String,
                  name :- String]
    (ok)))
```

what's the appropriate way of making name optional? Is it:

```
(POST* "/register" []
    :body-params [username :- String,
                  password :- String,
                  {name :- String nil}]
    (ok)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you know it uses `letk` plumbing notation and as far as I recall the syntax is correct but the default value should be consistent with the expected type so I'd say it should be `""` rather than `nil` as `(string? nil)` => `false`

```
(POST* "/register" []
    :body-params [username :- String,
                  password :- String,
                  {name :- String ""}]
    (ok)))
```

Comment: Where is this documented? I only found this now, months after using Compojure.